# Naming a file in python with sockets

Tags: python-3.x, python-sockets

I am creating a file that you can send files to a remote Ubuntu server.
however, when I send the name of it, I put print and it is just " b'' "
How do I make it so I can open the file?

Client.py

```
import socket
with socket.socket() as s:
    s.connect(('139.59.173.187',8000))
    with open('User.txt','rb') as f:
        s.sendall(f.read())
    name = input("What would you like it to be saved as?")
    s.send(name)
```

Server.py

```
import socket
with socket.socket() as s:
    s.connect(('139.59.173.187',8000))
    with open('User.txt','rb') as f:
        s.sendall(f.read())
    name = input("What would you like it to be saved as?")
    s.send(name)
```

Thanks in advance

`

Comment: Both _server.py_ and _client.py_ files are same.

Answer (score 0):

1. Your both server.py and client.py files are same. I think you mistakenly duplicated them.
2. About Problem :
3. Try to send the name first to the remote server
4. clients.py (in python3)

   ```
   import socket

   with socket.socket() as s:
       s.connect(('127.0.0.1',22599))

       name = input("What would you like it to be saved as?")

       s.send(name.encode('utf-8'))

       with open('xyz.txt','rb') as f:
           s.sendall(f.read())
   ```
5. server.py (in python2.7)

   ```
   import socket   # Import socket module
   s = socket.socket()         
   host = '127.0.0.1' #Ge Local Machine
   port = 22599               
   s.bind((host, port)) # Bind to the port
   s.listen(3)    #wait for client to join
   while True:
       c, addr = s.accept()     
       print 'Connection Accepted From',addr
       print "File is comming ...."
       file = c.recv(1024)     #get file name first from client
       #opening file first

       f = open(file,'wb')      #open that file or create one
       l = c.recv(1024)         #get input
       while (l):

           print "Receiving...File Data"
           f.write(l)            #save input to file
           l = c.recv(1024)      #get again until done

       f.close()

   c.send('Thank you for connecting')
   c.close()
   ```
6. Thank You

Comment: Thank you for this i was thinking this but didnt know. thanks alot